# Field settings are not being exported with Features

Tags: commerce, features

I have a product content type that has a product reference field. Under the Product types that can be referenced section there is a list of product types that can be referenced. I have selected one of these. 
When exporting/importing this content type, the field settings (eg. the selected referenced product) are not exported. How could i export this without selecting the referenced product manually.

Comment: I don't understand properly your entire problem but if the setting could not be exported by Features module, you can try to install Strongarm that allows you to export with the rest of the Feature all the settings saved in DB in code.

Comment: I have installed Strongarm but that doesn't help my problem. The settings are not being exported.

Comment: You don't find this setting in Strongarm section when you update your Features? Neither in your content-type's?

Answer (score 0):

The setting got exported but could not be set, because it was referencing an nonexistent product type.

On the old site i had a Recurring Product type w. a "recurring_product" machine name. I wanted to export the display for this. On the new site only a "recurring" product type existed and therefore could not match the setting.